# What are the concurrency implications of calling RefreshEndpoint.refresh() a Spring Cloud Config application?

Tags: spring-cloud

I'm doing a proof of concept at my company with Spring Cloud Config, using a GIT repository. Since I have a pretty fixed infrastructure, I can't have a RabbitMQ broker for Spring Cloud Bus, therefore I'm thinking of embedding the Spring Cloud Config Server in our apps and calling `RefreshEndpoint.refresh()` every couple of minutes.

One of the main things I'd like to know is what are the concurrency implications of calling `RefreshEndpoint.refresh()`? If there is a request already going on, could it have any issues?

Comment: The current request will use existing, not refreshed beans. Subsequent requests will get the refreshed beans.

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb. I was taking a look at the code, and it looks like the `@RefreshScope` beans are always refreshed even if the properties have not changed, but you do have a variable for the changed properties in the method...wouldn't it make sense to only refresh if there was a change?

Comment: You are correct, `@RefreshScope` beans are always refreshed.